# Check for dialog box event using windows API in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, office-interop, dialog, powerpoint-2010

I'm trying to check for dialog box open and close events in powerpoint 2010 (example: Saveas dialog box) using C#.net. Is there any other way to find out the events?

Comment: need more clarity.. please provide more details..

Comment: Are you automating PowerPoint or is it running standalone?

Comment: Do you specifically need to monitor dialogs or do you need to respond to save/open events in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the windows messages to understand when a window is open.

have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . This should point you to the right direction

**WM_SHOWWINDOW message (Windows)**
*Sent to a window when the window is about to be hidden or shown.
A window receives this message through its WindowProc function.*